# Is there an attribute or compiler flag to remove the need to specify type constraints on extension methods of generic interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, extension-methods, c#-7.3

I have an interface like this:

```cs
public interface SomeInterface<A, B, C>
where A : SomeAClass, SomeAClass2
where B : SomeBClass
where C : SomeCClass, SomeBClass, EtcClass
{
  A ObjA { get; }
  B ObjB { get; }
  IList<C> ObjC { get; }
}
```

My classes inherit this interface. My question comes from my extension methods. If I do this:

```cs
public static bool DoesThisCompile<A, B, C>(this SomeInterface<A, B, C> i)
/*
where A : SomeAClass, SomeAClass2
where B : SomeBClass
where C : SomeCClass, SomeBClass, EtcClass
*/
{
  return false;
}
```

It doesn't work, and copy-pasting the constraints (for many extension methods) from the interface is a lot of work, very ugly, and in my opinion, unnecessary. Is there some attribute I can place somewhere or some compiler flag to automatically grab the correct constraints? I know I can create another non-generic interface, but I really do not want to do that for this project (design-wise it doesn't help and just adds lots of bloat to my classes), and it wouldn't even work because of collections.

Comment: Ugly or not and whether you like it or not, its a requirement of the language feature and there is no known switch to disable it as far as i know. Disabling it would be a sure fire way to introduce runtime bugs into a large system

Comment: I expected it to infer the types based on the constraints of the interface, since there's no reason it should infer each type is "object" by default, and extension methods cannot go in generic static classes. Oh well

Comment: "My classes inherit this interface." No, my dear. Your classes *implement* this interface. There's a difference.

Comment: You know what I meant

Comment: @Kermalis I know what you meant, but are you sure you're aware of the difference? because I wasn't when I wrote my comment and still I'm still wondering about this. Computers are annoyingly nitpicky, so In software development, it's kinda important to use the correct terminology.